# Detect a horizontal plane using ARKIT and capture its image

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I am already detecting the horizontal planes in my AR app using ARKit and SceneKit.

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
sceneView.session.run(configuration)
sceneView.delegate = self
```

This calls the delegate method on plane detection.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
            // 1
            guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }

            // 2
            let width = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.x)
            let height = CGFloat(planeAnchor.extent.z)

            let plane = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)

    }
```

But is there any way that I can get the plane surface which was detected and capture its image somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

It is, but I don't think it'll be simple.

Once you get the delegate call* with the new plane anchor you can capture a frame from the scene, calculate the corners of the plane as 3D points, and convert those to screen points (`SCNScene` has some useful methods for this).

Then you'll have to somehow fix the perspective on the image using those four screen points, and use their fixed values to get the rect on the transformed image, then you can crop it.

I found an algorithm that's similar to what you need, but it's not written in Swift https://github.com/bahmutov/fix-perspective

*you can also ask users to press a button in order to get a photo with a better angle.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will check and get back.